# Modal se cierra después de dar ok en el alert

Tags: php, sweetalert2

Tengo un formulario de registros de salas para reunión. En el código hay una validación de que si la sala esta ocupada se muestra un alert diciendo que la sala ya esta ocupada, pero cuando clico en el OK del alert se cierra el modal y el usuario tiene que abrir otra vez el formulario y rellenarlo.

¿Hay alguna manera de que cuando le des ok en el alert no se cierre el modal? Ya hice de todo y no funciona nada.

Les dejo el código que funciona pero se cierra el modal.

```
   if ( mysqli_num_rows( $q ) == 0 ) {
          if ( $inicio_normal > $final_normal ) {
                echo '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>';
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                    Swal.fire({
                      icon: "error",
                      title: "¡Oops!",
                      text: "El horario de inico no puede ser mayor que el horario de fin, por favor corrija el horario."
                    }).then(function () {
                      window.location.href = "home.php";
                    });
                  });
                </script>';
                exit();

          } else {
            $query = "INSERT INTO agenda VALUES(null,'$titulo','$body', '', '', '$clase','$inicio','$final','$inicio_normal','$final_normal')";
            $conexion->query( $query )or die( '<script type="text/javascript">alert("error")</script>' );
            header( "Location: home.php" );
          }
        } else {
        echo '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            Swal.fire({
              icon: "error",
              title: "¡Oops!",
              text: "Esta sala está ocupada en este horario, por favor elija otro horario o sala."
            }).then(function () {
              window.location.href = "home.php";
            });
          });
        </script>';
        exit();
        }
```

Cuando saco el `window.location.href = "home.php";` vuelve a la home.php pero en blanco. O sea sin solución.

Answer (score 1):

Primero podrías pasar el código de home.php para saber qué hace y también podrías decir si el código que muestras está en un archivo separado o no. O lo llamas desde un formulario. etc. O sea sería bueno para entender mejor darnos un poco más de contexto al problema.

Dicho eso, creo que puedo interpretar el problema.

Tenés que recordar que el modal se cierra NO POR el Alert en si, sino porque cuando haces windows.location desde javascript - o location si estas en php - la página home.php se carga de nuevo, y al cargar de nuevo vuelve a empezar: el modal cerrado, las variables inicializadas de nuevo,  etc

Si no querés que eso suceda deberías pensar en alguna manera de usar la SESION para guardar los valores de los inputs y en el home.php verificar eso. Entonces por ejemplo si esta definida alguna variable que tenías en el formulario se lanza el alert y se vuelve a abrir el modal de nuevo.

Básicamente, en el home.php

1. abrir una sesión
2. verificas si existe alguna variable de error o guardada por el script de verificación en la session usando la función isset()

Ejemplo

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['Horario']['error'])) {

    // existe un error de verificacion 

 } //escribis tu script javascript lanzando el modal

 lanzas el alert pero no haces windows.location

 abris el modal desde javascript


 } else {

    // este else es para hacer un comentario nomas
    // si no hay error no se lanza el alert ni nada
 }
```

codigo de home.php normal

3. en el modal podes recuperar los valores de los inputs si los guardaste en la sesión

Ejemplo si estaba en un formulario

```
 <form action="no se como se llama tu archivo php">

 <input type ="text" name="hora" value=" 
 <?php  

 if( isset($_SESSION['Horario']['hora'])) {
        // significa que hay una variable hora guardada en sesion
      echo $_SESSION['Horario']['hora'];
 } else {

      echo "";    // el value queda vacio
 } 

 //una vez que pude recuperar los valores guardados en sesion y los utilizo
 // puedo lipiar la sesion 

 unset( $_SESSION['Horario'] );   //elimno la variable guardada previamente   

 ? >

 ">     <---- ojo esto cierra la apertura del value y la etiqueta input
 </form>
```

En tu archivo xxxx  - no sé como se llama tu archivo php -, como ejemplo si hay algún error, haces

```
 $_SESSION['Horario']['error']= true;  //aviso del error
 $_SESSION['Horario']['hora'] = $_REQUEST['hora´]; //aca guardo el valor del input en session
```

y redireccionas de nuevo al home.php

Espero que te sirva. Perdón por la extension.

Saludos